# JPEG read #of non-zero DCT coefficients

Tags: header, jpeg, dct

I'm using jpeglib to modify some DCT coefficients of the image. But, i'm changing only non-zero DCT coefficients. Is there any way get the total non-zero DCT elements in an image? Is there any header information that you know?

Comment: The number of non-zero DCT coefficients is not written into the JPEG header; you'll need to count it yourself.

Comment: thanx for your reply!